# Rails 5 - Render New with Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have checked old similar post but but I'm still having problems.

When I create a new listing the URL looks as below:
http://localhost:3000/listings/new?plan=1

In the form_for I'm hiding some fields when plan=1

```
<%= form_for(@listing) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan, :value => @plan %>

  <%= f.label :Title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

  <!-- don't show description for standard plan -->
  <% if @plan != 1.to_s %>
    <%= f.label :Description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10,
      placeholder: "Describe your business...", class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
```

In the ListingsController I set the plan in before action:

```
before_action :set_plan,        only: [:new, :create]

    def set_plan
      @plan = params[:plan]
    end
```

so I can use it as hidden field on the form above.

My problem starts when I save the form with errors.
The new form URL changes to http://localhost:3000/listings.
I can see the @plan=1 still on the form:

```
<input value="1" type="hidden" name="listing[plan]" id="listing_plan" />
```

, but now the form is showing all fields (which should be hidden due to this condition <% if @plan != 1.to_s %>)

Actions in ListingsController:

```
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params) if logged_in?
    @plan = @listing.plan

    if @listing.save
      flash[:success] = "Listing created!"
      redirect_to @listing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I have tried something like that but no success:
render :action => 'new', :plan => @listing.plan
and few other things

How can I hide those fields on error?

Comment: you cannot access the plan parameter with `@plan`, rather use `params[:plan]`

Comment: When I go to the first link I'm in the New action:
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  plan: '1'
  controller: listings
  action: new

but when I save the for with errors it goes into Create:

    parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      plan: '1'
      title: ''
    permitted: false
  commit: Create Listing
  controller: listings
  action: create

The plan is there but when I do this at he begging of Create:
\@plan = params[:plan]
it doesn't get the value for \@plan. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this by modifying your `ListingsController` to set the plan on create.  Specifically, in **ListingsController.rb**:

```
# app/controllers/listings_controller.rb
before_action :set_plan, only: [:new, :create]
```

Also, be sure your `listing_params` method permits `:plan`.

If you want this to function on update, then add `:update` to your `before_action` as well.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried that but no luck, plan is permitted on params. Set_plan before create wasn't passing any value so I added this line in Create - \@plan = \@listing.plan (see edited question).  I can see the value on the submitted form with errors - <input value="1" type="hidden" name="listing[plan]" id="listing_plan" />, so I don't understand why the IF doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have it fixed.

```
@plan = params[:plan]
```

was returning string (when the field in DB is integer), so I changed it to:

```
@plan = params[:plan].to_i
```

and now in the form I have the below for all actions:

```
<% if @plan != 1 %>
```